# Special Character Whitelist with Tesseract (OCR)

Tags: c#, char, ocr, tesseract, whitelist

Iam trying to read out some Money Values via OCR, the Issue is that I want to tell him which chars he should recognize.

This is my current whitelist

```
       Version : Tesseract from Charles Weld v3.0.2
       tessedit_char_whitelist "0123456789,.$"
```

How do I include the Cent (¢) ?

Update 1: If I add the ¢ to the list it wont recognize it.

Comment: `tessedit_char_whitelist = "0123456789,.$¢"`?

Comment: @juharr tried that first didnt work :(...

Comment: That's definitely information you should include in the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after failing to understand the question the first time I have a more relevant answer.

```
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789,.$¢");
```

Supply the name of the parameter and the value as a string, just as you would in a config file. Eg

```
SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "xyz"); to whitelist x, y and z.
```

Also make sure

```
SetVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1 or 0");
```

to set numeric-only mode or disable numeric only mode. Which ever one meets your needs I would guess in your case it should be disabled because you are using characters as well as numbers.

Hope this helps! If not let me know and I'll remove the answer(I had to use an answer because I can't comment under 50 rep, otherwise I would have commented first to get more information about the problem) Cheers!

Comment: Sorry about the poor first attempt at an answer, I derped super hard.

Comment: That worked perfectly, are you experinced with ocr? I need some help with improvements of the recognition is there a way to "teach" it ? Sometimes it wont see the Spaces...

Comment: I'm not experienced at all, the only experience I have is setting up a test project to test my answer to your question. I did find some relevant documentation though, https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract, and more specifically, https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00.